# debug mode for SocketIOServer

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue on my page.

I formated my os and have not changed the code, am working in a virtualenvironment where I `pip -r install requrements.txt` and now am having issues getting the page.

Where My page started the websocket connection before, now i am getting a 405 method not allowed.

I have `app.debug = True` but see no debugging information and I just get method not allowed when submitting my request.

I need as much debug information as possible with this so I can troubleshoot.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config.from_object(settings)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    monkey.patch_all()
    listen_address = '0.0.0.0'
    listen_port = 5000
    print 'Starting Server on: http://{0}:{1}'.format(listen_address, listen_port)
    SocketIOServer((listen_address, listen_port), app, resource="socket.io").serve_forever()
```

Comment: Is there a debug statement in your settings object?

Comment: Makes no difference:                                           127.0.0.1 - - [2014-11-24 14:37:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4804 0.032499
127.0.0.1 - - [2014-11-24 14:37:47] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 323 0.004107

Comment: here are my imports:                                                 from redis import Redis
import settings
from socketio import socketio_manage
from flask import Flask
from gevent import monkey
from socketio.server import SocketIOServer
import os
from celery import Celery
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import send_file
from flask import Response
import supportcoregrapher
import coregrapherconf
import requests

Comment: from socketio.server import SocketIOServer

Comment: Post imports in main post not in the comments... Could you simply change the debug mode in your settings object?

Answer (score 0):

I use [flask-socketio](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). May you are using gevent-socketio?
With flask-socketio it will work with

```
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO

monkey.patch_all()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(settings)
socketio = SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app)
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

and just turn debug mode on in your settings...